# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_CATCH

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm trying a loop through a Facebook Graph API loop via a foreach loop but I'm getting this error: "PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_CATCH".

Any thoughts?

Here's the code:

```
// WRITING FIRST 50 FRIENDS LIKES

$i = 0;
foreach($userfriends[data] as $value) {

if($key == "id"){
    $friend_id = $value;        
}

try {
    $username = $friend_id;
    $uservar = '/'.$username.'/likes?fields=id,category&limit=20';
    $userlikes = $facebook->api($uservar);
}         

//  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
//  error_log($e);
//  }

$id = $userlikes[$i][id];
$cat = $userlikes[$i][category];

// WRITING FRIEND LIKES TO DATABASE

$sql="INSERT INTO likes (like_id, category, friend_id) VALUES ('$id', '$cat', '$friend_id');";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_free_result($sql);
$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have your catch commented out and it is expecting catch

Answer (score 1):

You have a try block without catch.

```
try {
$username = $friend_id;
$uservar = '/'.$username.'/likes?fields=id,category&limit=20';
$userlikes = $facebook->api($uservar);
} catch {

//exception happened
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have commented out the "catch" , re-enable it and the parse error would go away.

Answer (score 0):

Your `catch` block is commented out - either uncomment it or comment out the `try` as well.  Every `try` must have at least one `catch` to handle any exceptions thrown inside the `try`.